# Distinguish one and two-dimensional container using concepts

Tags: c++, containers, concept, c++23

I want to distinguish one and two-dimensional containers using concepts. My first try was the following:

```
template<typename C>
concept Container1D = requires(C c) {
    std::begin(c);
    std::end(c);
    c[0];
};

template<typename C>
concept Container2D = requires(C c) {
    std::begin(c);
    std::end(c);
    c[0, 0]; // interpreted as comma-operator
};
```

But oviously this does not work, because the expression `0, 0` is interpreted as a comma-operator and so the second concept matches also one-dimensional container.

Is there a way to require a two-dimensional `operator[a, b]`?

Comment: `c[0, 0]` -> `c[0][0]` ???

Comment: Why not just spell it out, like `c.operator[](0,0)`?

Comment: @AdrianMole C++23 lets you overload `c[0,0]`.

Comment: It looks like only MSVC does this thing. GCC and Clang refuse to interpret `,` as comma operator here.

Comment: So under your definition, what is the container type that satisfies `Container2D`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Comma operator issues

Not every compiler supports [multi-dimensional subscript operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Array_subscript_operator) yet.
At the time of writing, [the compiler support is this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23):

| C++23 Feature | GCC | Clang | MSVC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Multi-dimensional subscript operator | 12 | 15 | (none) |

As a temporary workaround, you can use `c.operator[](0, 0)`, which works as long as there is a multi-dimensional subscript overload in the standard library, even if the core language feature isn't supported yet.

#### Issues with your concepts

It's generally better to build concepts on top of other existing `concept`s.
For instance, there is [`std::ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range):

```cpp
// in namespace std::ranges
template<typename T>
concept range = requires( T& t ) {
  ranges::begin(t); // equality-preserving for forward iterators
  ranges::end  (t);
};

// building on top of that...
template<typename R>
concept Range1D = std::ranges::range<R> && requires(R& r) {
    { r[0]; } -> std::ranges::range_value_t<R>;
};
```

However, this concept is really strange because `r[0]` implies that your container has random access, so using a stronger requirement like [`std::ranges::random_access_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/random_access_range) would be better:

```cpp
template<typename R>
concept Range1D = std::ranges::random_access_range<R> && requires(R& r) {
    { r[0]; } -> std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>;
};

template<typename R>
concept Range2D = std::ranges::random_access_range<R> && requires(R& r) {
    { r.operator[](0, 0); } -> std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>;
};
```